# A simple Fourier Transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

I am a bit stuck with this small basic signal.

I have this

$$y(t)=\frac{\sin(200\pi\,t)}{\pi\,t}$$

and I want to take its Fourier Transformation. Obviously it looks like the sinc function. But that $200$ confuses me a lot.

Comment: You can find the Fourier transform of the sinc function in a typical table of Fourier transforms. That'll at least let you check your answer.

Comment: If the $200$ confuses you, just do everything for $x(t)= \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$ and note that $y(t) = 200 x(200t)$. If you don't know how the Fourier transform behaves under scaling, take a look at your textbook again or read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, the question is, how to rewrite that y(t), into a sinc(t) function , so i can use the FT table. –  RatzaJR

Elaborating on my comment, where I already answered this, we have that $y(t) = 200 \operatorname{sinc}(200t)$. Therefore, denoting the Fourier transform of a function $f$ by $\hat{f}$,
$$\hat{y}(\xi)=200 \frac{1}{200} \widehat{\operatorname{sinc}}\left( \frac{\xi}{200}\right) = \operatorname{rect} \left( \frac{\xi}{200}\right) = \begin{cases} 1 \qquad \text{if $|\xi|< 100$} \\ 0 \qquad \text{if $|\xi| \geq 100$}\end{cases},$$
where the first equality follows from the basic fact that for real numbers $a,b$ where $a \neq 0$ and a function $f$, the Fourier transform of $a f(bx)$ is given by $\frac{a}{|b|} \hat{f}\left(\frac{\xi}{b} \right)$. You should really try to understand this step, otherwise you're toasted in your exam...

Answer (score -1):

$$Y(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y(t) \cos(\omega t) d\omega=2\int_0^{\infty}y(t) \cos(\omega t) d\omega=(sign(200\pi-\omega)+sign(200\pi+\omega))/2$$

Comment: What does this have to do with the question asked?

Comment: I thought that $Y(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $y(t)$.

Comment: In other words, the question is, how to rewrite that y(t), into a sinc(t) function , so i can use the FT table.

Comment: @RatzaJR. Thanks for clarification. My answer is to the question: "I have this $y(t)$ and I want to take its Fourier Transformation". wikipedia first definition of sinc function is $\text{sinc} x=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. So answer to your question "how to rewrite that $y(t)$, into a $\text{sinc}(t)$ function" is $y(t)=200\text{sinc}(200\pi t)$.